# awk regex and space inside

Tags: regex, awk

Why my awk script

```
BEGIN {
  FS = "][ \t\v]+"
}

# Note space after + in the end of the regex.
NF == 2 && $1 ~ /[:alpha:][:digit:]+ / {
  print $1, "<<<";
}
```

Doesn't match any string in the file like the following:

```
I1130 15:18:42.526808 17329 thrift_bridge.cpp:126] AAA
E1130 15:18:42.527042 16076 thrift_bridge.hpp:288] BBB
```

But if I remove space, both lines are in the output.

Comment: It's hard to tell from a script that doesn't do what you want what it is you DO want. Please edit your question to state what your `FS` is supposed to match and what the regexp in your condition is supposed to match,

Answer (score 5):

It's because your character class syntax is wrong:

```
/[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+ /
```

Without square brackets `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]` aren't seen like pre-defined POSIX character classes but like basic classes.

`/[:alpha:][:digit:]+/` is the same than `/[ahlp:][dgit:]+/`, and matches `p:` on each line.

As @John1024 noticed it, mawk doesn't support POSIX character classes, so you must write:

```
/[a-zA-Z][0-9]+ /
```

or use gawk since it is available under linux.

Comment: Seems like it just don't understand char classes. The variant you suggested I tried as well and it doesn't work. mawk, Ubuntu 14.

Comment: I just tried it with `mawk` version 1.3.3 on Debian and I can confirm that `mawk` does not understand character classes.  By contrast, under GNU awk, the classes work well.